# ADF mapping data flow postgres error column is of type jsonb

Tags: postgresql, azure-data-factory, jsonb

I am using a mapping data flow in azure data factory to copy data between two postgres databases.  The table has a column with a datatype of `jsonb`.  It looks something like this:

```
Create table mytable 
(
    id int,
    json_column jsonb
);
```

The schema is the same in both databases.  The error message kept getting cut off in ADF, so in my process of debugging I limited it to a single row, which happened to have NULL for the json column.  The insert statement that ADF created was like this:

```
INSERT INTO "T_6726_7518bded039e4697aedcfafdd213e402" ("id","json_column","r0c0604bf127847bdac0e8012a40d8651") 
VALUES (123,NULL,8)
```

This returns the error:

> ERROR: column "json_column" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character
> Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

The same statement runs fine in pg_admin.  Is there a work around for this?  Is there actually no support for `jsonb` columns?

Comment: that has nothing to do with json be when you insert NULL, so what exactly are you trying to insert

Comment: CAST the null to jsonb: `CAST(NULL AS jsonb)` to avoid any ambiguity

Comment: @nbk in the case of this example row, the value is null.  Other rows have valid json.  However, null is a valid value, and, as I noted, this statement runs fine when executed manually.  It just errors out in ADF.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I am trying to avoid hardcoding the source and target so I can use a single mapping data flow for all tables being copied.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to copy data from a Postgres SQL table with null values in the name column to another table using mapped data flow, I got the same error as shown below:

[image]

This may be a bug in data flow. I have tried the following workaround:

I added a derived transformation to the source and modified the column with null values using the expression below:

```
iif(isNull(<columnName>), '{"value": null}', <columnName>)
```

[image]

Data preview of the derived column transformation:

[image]

I added the following script as a post-copy script to the sink in the sink settings tab:

```
update <tableName> set name = NULL where <columnName> = '{
  "value": null
}'
```

[image]

When I ran the data flow activity with the reference of the data flow below, the table data copied successfully as shown:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer -- this works and it reveals a little more about this bug with ADF.  The only issue I have is that I want to make the dataflow dynamic (no set schema), but I suppose I can accomplish the same querying the metadata first and building a source query and postscript from that.  If there is a better way, I would really like to know

Comment: AFAIK, this might be a workaround for this issue, as it could be a bug.